# Programmatic way to place a website into a new Word file... in Java

Tags: java, url, ms-word

Is it possible to programmatically place the contents of a web page into a Word file?

To further complicate this, I'd like to do these steps in Java (using JNI if I must).

Here are the steps I want to do programmatically, followed by ways that I would do this manually today:

1. Provide a method with a URL *(Manually: Open page in Firefox)*
2. Copy the contents of that URL *(Manually: Ctrl-A to select all)*
3. Create a new Word document *(Manually: Open Microsoft Word)*
4. Paste the contents of the URL into Word *(Manually: Ctrl-V to paste)*
5. Save the Word file *(Manually: Save the Word file)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do better imho downloading the file using HTTP then create a new word file using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) and copying the HTTP stream inside the word file

Answer (score 1):

[HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can be used to programmatically open the page (posing as Firefox if necessary), and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can be used to create a Microsoft Word file (in Word 97 format).

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2005/03/29/java-and-ms-word.aspx) describes a way to manipulate MS-Word doc files from within Java, just using string replace, or XSLT.

As for grabbing the content of a URL, that is the simpler part of the task, which you can accomplish with something pretty simple.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;


public class util
{

  public String HttpGet(String urlString)
  {
    String resultData= null;
    try
    {
      URL url = new URL(urlString);
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      conn.connect();

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      String line = null;
      java.lang.StringBuffer sb1= new java.lang.StringBuffer();
      while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        sb1.append(line);

      resultData= sb.toString();
      mStatus= "gotprice";

    } 
    catch (java.lang.Throwable e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultData;
  }


}
```